# Como subir multiples imagenes con $cordovaFileTransfer

Tags: angularjs, ionic, ng-cordova

estoy programando una aplicacion con angular y ionic compatible con android,
necesito subir5 imagenes a un servidor y utilice $cordovaFileTransfer para este fin, el problema es que las intentar subir las 5 imagenes lo que hace es subirme 5 veces la ultima foto, alguna idea de este error?, lei en alguna parte que es un bug del cache del dispositivo y debia cambiarle el nombre al URI de cada imagen pero no se como hacerlo.

```
                      var cont = 0;
                      var id = response.data;
                      var indice = 1;

                      for (var i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++) {

                               var path = $scope.imagenes[i];
                               var options = {

                               fileKey: "file",
                               fileName: "ID-" + id + "-N-" + indice + ".jpg",
                               chunkedMode: false,
                               mimeType: "image/jpg"

                               };

                               indice++;

                            $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, path , options)
                            .then(function(result) {  
                              cont++;
                              if(cont == 5)
                                 $window.alert("TODO OK!");

                            }, function(err) {
                                      $window.alert("ERROR" + JSON.stringify(err));

                            }); 
                        $scope.imagenes[i] = "";
                     }
```

- EDITADO

Encontre una posible solucion en otro post de stackoverflow el problema es que el codigo no esta adaptado para angular y al parecer de esta forma no funciona!

```
function renameFile(src, callback) {
    var d = new Date();
    //find the FileEntry for the file on the device
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(src, function(fileEntry) {
        //get the parent directory (callback gives a DirectoryEntry)
        fileEntry.getParent(function(parent) {
            //rename the file, prepending a timestamp.
            fileEntry.moveTo(parent, d.getTime() + fileEntry.name, function(s) {
                //Callback with the new URL of the file.
                callback(s.nativeURL);
            }, function(error) {
                alert('Error on moving file!');
                callback(src); //Fallback, use the src given
            });
        }, function(error) {
            alert('Error on getting parent!');
            callback(src); //Fallback
        });
    }, function(error) {
        alert('Error on resolveLocalFileSystemURI!');
        callback(src); //Fallback
    });
}`
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema no es de cache, si no que la variable indice no contiene el valor que se le asigna en cada bucle, si no que toma el valor que tenga indice en el momento de ejecución de la función que en este seria 5, este tipo de error es muy común y se pueden resolver con las famosas closures, las cuales son funciones que manejan variables independientes, por lo que a cada closure le mandariamos el valor del indice en cada ciclo quedando el código de la siguiente manera:

```
var cont = 0; // este es tu contador 
function myClosure(i,id,limite){
  var path = $scope.imagenes[i];
  var options = {
    fileKey: "file",
    fileName: "ID-" + id + "-N-" + i + ".jpg",
    chunkedMode: false,
    mimeType: "image/jpg"
  };
  $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, path , options)
  .then(function(result) {
     cont++;
     console.log(cont);
     if(cont === limite){
       $window.alert("TODO OK!");
       cont = 0; //volvemos el contador a 0
     }
   },function(err) {
       $window.alert("ERROR" + JSON.stringify(err)+ " unicamente se subieron "+cont+" imagenes");
  }); 
  $scope.imagenes[i] = "";
}

var id = response.data;
for (var i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++) {
   myClosure(i,id,5)//aca invocamos la funcion con los valores que queremos
}
```

Nota que el contador debe ser de alcance globar para que la closure lo aumente cada vez que una imagen se suba correctamente.

Comment: Te agradezco por la respuesta pero intente tu modificacion y el error persiste, sigo pensando que es un error del cache de android (donde se almacenan las imagenes subidas desde el dispositivo) porque efectivamente en cada iteracion la variable fileName es diferente y el path tambien cambia, osea que en teoria deberia funcionar pero no lo hace :(

Answer (score 1):

No se si te sirva que hagas una funcion que se encargue de subir las imagenes y tu por parametro entregues solo el path, no creo que sea por cache, yo tambien trabaje subiendo varias imagenes a la vez y siempre lo hice con una funcion en particular que se encargara solo de subir. Tanto en Android como en iOS me funciono.

```
    var cont = 0;
    var id = response.data;
    var indice = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

        var path = $scope.imagenes[i];
        var options = {

            fileKey: "file",
            fileName: "name",
            chunkedMode: false,
            mimeType: "image/jpg"

        };
        uploadImage(path);

    }

    function uploadImage(path) {
        var options = {

            fileKey: "file",
            fileName: "ID-" + id + "-N-" + indice + ".jpg",
            chunkedMode: false,
            mimeType: "image/jpg"

        };
        $cordovaFileTransfer.upload(server, path, options)
        .then(function(result) {
            console.log("bien");

        }, function(err) {
            $window.alert("ERROR" + JSON.stringify(err));
        });
    }
```